# What could be the difference between "volume" and "number of trades" in stock market analysis software?

Tags: technical-analysis

My broker software reports 2 different numbers for "volume" and "number of trades". However, if I look on [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/041015/why-trading-volume-important-investors.asp) it lists "volume" to be the number of trades. The volume number is usually 2-3 digits larger than the other number. What do these two different numbers mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For stocks, volume is the number of *shares* traded. A trade can be (and almost always is) for multiple shares, and is usually a multiple of 100, which is why the volume is 2-3 digits more than the number of trades.

I don't see where your link defines "volume" as "number of trades".

Comment: For me the page lists as the first sentence: `Trading volume is the total number of shares of a security that were traded during a given period of time.`. In my broker's documentation it has a code `v` for volume and then another piece of information it calls `n` which it says are the number of trades.

Comment: "Trading volume is the total number of ***shares*** of a security..." One trade can be for 100  (or 5, or 10,000) shares

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense as to why both are integers.